# Warning In log(sum(1 - compE.root)) : NaNs produced package hisse

Tags: phylogeny

I am having the following error after running `hisse` function from `hisse` package:

`In log(sum(1 - compE.root)) : NaNs produced`

Did anyone have the same warning? How can I solve it?

I do not know if the problem is my dataset or the phylogeny inserted

Thanks